# React native BottomTabNavigator Strange Animation

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-navigation

I created a BottomTabNavigator for 3 different screens, when changing tabs on the screen after one change a strange animation appears which makes all scren go up and down for the next tab changes , how can I disable this strange animation?

Video : https://youtu.be/yN8Vm7C_4eo

Code

```js
import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation-stack";

import { createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";

import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "react-navigation-tabs";

const createNavigator = (mainScreen) => {
  const Navigator = createStackNavigator({
    screen1: mainScreen,
    SettingsScreen: SettingsScreen,
    InfoScreen: InfoScreen,
  });
  return Navigator;
};

const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  GünlükListe: createNavigator(TodayListScreen),
  Favoriler: createNavigator(FavoritesScreen),
  BütünListe: createNavigator(AllListScreen),
});

export default createAppContainer(TabNavigator);
```

Comment: Did you try to assign the screen directly to `Favoriler` instead of using `createNavigator`?

Comment: When I create screens without calling createStackNavigator() navigation bar,header,header-left and header-right buttons become unvisible , I should use createStackNavigator() so createNavigator.

Comment: Is there any reason why you are using the old versions of these packages? If there is none, I can provide you a code snippet with the up to date way of doing it.

Comment: There is no specific reason, I used version 4.0 because I was following from an udemy course , I would like to try the newest version If you can share the code ... thank you

Answer (score 0):

The way you set up your Navigation cause bad performance. I suggest rewrite it in this sense.

```
const AuthStack = createStackNavigator({
  //config
})

const MainStack = createStackNavigator({
  //config
})


const BottomNav = createBottomTabNavigator({
//config
})

const MainAppStack = createStackNavigator({
 Main:MainStack,
 BottomNav: bottomNav
})

const Navigator = createSwitchNavigator({
Auth:Authstack,
MainApp: MainAppStack
})

export default createAppContainer(Navigator);
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved,I switched to react navigation v5 , and there is no strange animation like that in v5.